# Data coming from an API is not refreshing when I reload/navigate the webpage

Tags: angular, api

I am working in an angular project, in which there is a component where I show("GET" method) the data coming from an API in the frontend.

```
this.conversationsService
  .get(
    environment.API_ENDPOINT +
      '/api/v1/conversation/history/?conversation_id=' +
      this.conversation_id,
  )
  .subscribe((res: any) => {
    console.log(res);}
```

this is what we get from the above "GET" request

```
{
        "id": 856,
        "conversation_id": 8,
        "is_completed": false,
        "created_at": "2020-05-27T23:12:09.699392Z",
        "completion_datetime": null,
        "time_taken_to_complete_in_seconds": null,
        "speed_run": false,
        "user_response": []
    }
```

When the user interacts with this component the data is updating("POST" method) in the same API. This is what is shown in the Postman, that the "POST" is successfully working.

```
 {
        "id": 856,
        "conversation_id": 8,
        "is_completed": false,
        "created_at": "2020-05-27T23:12:09.699392Z",
        "completion_datetime": null,
        "time_taken_to_complete_in_seconds": null,
        "speed_run": false,
        "user_response": [
            {
                "created_at": "2020-05-27T23:15:46.287839Z",
                "dialog": {
                    "id": 44,
                    "message": "Hi new_arka_iitk, I’m Robin.",
                    "dialog_images": [],
                    "is_last": false
                },
                "option": {
                    "id": 42,
                    "message": "Hi Robin . Nice to meet you.",
                    "option_images": []
                }
            },
            {
                "created_at": "2020-05-27T23:15:48.487096Z",
                "dialog": {
                    "id": 45,
                    "message": "Uh-huh … ",
                    "dialog_images": [],
                    "is_last": false
                },
                "option": {
                    "id": 43,
                    "message": "So…. how was your day Robin?",
                    "option_images": []
                }
            },
            {
                "created_at": "2020-05-27T23:15:52.760567Z",
                "dialog": {
                    "id": 46,
                    "message": "I’ve been better.",
                    "dialog_images": [],
                    "is_last": false
                },
                "option": {
                    "id": 44,
                    "message": "Oh…. what happened?",
                    "option_images": []
                }
            }
```

However, when I navigate out of that page and again navigate to the same page or reload the page,  the data shown is not updated in the frontend, though the data is updated in the backend. The data showing in the frontend is the same one as it showed when I first visited the component. After that, if I navigate out of that component and visit again to the same component the data is not updating.

I can see the data updating in the backend with the help of postman (I have attached the data from the postman above).
The only solution to this which I can get over this is to close the browser window(incognito) and again open it, this way it is able to fetch the latest data from the backend.

What can be the problem with the same? Any leads would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Could you post some code so we can see what might be going on. We would need to at least see the components code, where you're making the GET request, and what the GET request looks like.

Answer (score 1):

Are you writing this.conversationsService.get() function on the ngoninIt() life cycle? If yes, this might be a problem. You can use activated routes and call the 'get' function on it, so that it will get fired every time a user routes to the page.

Comment: Hi @Atul, I am not clear as to where exactly will I add the activated routes code. Will I have to add the activated routes in the ngOninit() ?

Comment: You can add the activated routes in the constructor section after making an object for activated routes and subscribing to the getcurrentNavigation() method.